# products show up on category page but not in collection

Tags: product, category

I created a featured products slider on the home page. It was inserted via the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="563" template="catalog/product/featured-products.phtml"}}
```

There are 24 products in the given category. They are showing up on the front end when you navigate to the featured-products.html category, but they are not all showing up for the static block on the home page. It seems they are not all in the collection. When I echo the following variable I get a 9, not a 24. I have reindexed and cleared cache. Any ideas?

```
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like paging.

Are you sure, that you removed the toolbar and that the standard-limit is 9?

You can check it here:

`System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Shop > Items per Page (?)`

- I have only the german version here at the moment :-/ And I'm not sure whether this is an extension.

And you can have a look into `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` there is the limit set.

Comment: How do I get all products in collection without changing the item per page limit. I want to keep the limit on the front end, but display all the products in my slider.

Comment: Nevermind I used this tutorial to figure it out http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/magento-for-designers-part-6/. Used this instead $cat_id = "563";   
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')  
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description'), 'inner')  
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id));

Comment: great :-) On this question on stackoverflow R.S. recommends to use `limit` as a parameter. I didn't find any hint in the code that this might work :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/15281192/1480397 But if you have time ,try.